# Work with JSON in C# Winforms Application

Tags: c#, winforms, json

So I am making an application in C# to read some information from the web, but it is a windows forms application. I get a JSON string, and I need to get some information from it. I know there is a library for that for C# web applications, but how can I use in in my windows forms application?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are many JSON libraries out there. Here are three suggestions that you could look into:

- [**Json.NET**](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx), a fairly popular library for JSON (de-)serialization.
- [**ServiceStack's JsonSerializer**](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text), according to [a comparison in this ServiceStack blog](http://mono.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=344) currently the fastest JSON (de-)serializer.
- I believe the .NET 4 Framework might also have JSON serialization (in the [**`System.Runtime.Serialization.Json` namespace**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) from the `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll` assembly; the namespace seems to have been available in .NET 3.5, but in a different assembly), but I've never looked at it closely.

Comment: +1 for JSON.NET. will work fine in your forms application also.

Answer (score -5):

JSON.NET is useless for VS2012 b/c the nuget packages of JSON.NET are broken for nuget 2.8 and VS2012 cannot get anything newer than nuget 2.8!