# How to evade downloading json file through WebBrowser control C#

Tags: c#, json, webbrowser-control

The `WebBrowser` control automatically downloads the response from the server (when I only use the tradional `WebBrowser.Navgiate()`), how do I ignore the file, or refuse the download (as it seems to pause my program)?

Edit:
This is the code:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("url/phpFile.php?parameters");
```

And this is what I get when I run it:

[image]

Comment: Why ignore it? You could ignore the response, but capture the file - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021709/how-to-capture-json-response-using-webbrowser-control

Comment: It will not work for me because I'm first login and only then can access this page.

Answer (score 2):

1.Open Notepad and paste the following:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00;
; Tell IE 7,8,9,10 to open JSON documents in the browser on Windows XP and later.
; 25336920-03F9-11cf-8FD0-00AA00686F13 is the CLSID for the "Browse in place" .
;
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\application/json]
"CLSID"="{25336920-03F9-11cf-8FD0-00AA00686F13}"
"Encoding"=hex:08,00,00,00
```

2.Save document as IE-Json.reg and then run it.

Tested on Windows 10 & Win 7

Answer (score 0):

As a extention to NishantVerma.Me's awnser, this can be done programmatically.
There is only one drawback, this has to be done with administrator privileges.
My example is for a 32 bit application on a 64 bit device.

```
   private bool SetRegistery()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var hklm = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.ClassesRoot, RegistryView.Registry64))
            {
                using (RegistryKey key = hklm.OpenSubKey(@"MIME\Database\Content Type\application/json", true))
                {
                    if (key != null)
                    {
                        key.SetValue("CLSID", "{25336920-03F9-11cf-8FD0-00AA00686F13}");
                        key.SetValue("Encoding", new byte[] { 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 });
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        return false;
    }
```